# Chrome keeps crashing on my Macbook Ventura

Tags: macos, google-chrome, memory

I have searched online before but all the solutions I found seem to be too generic and hard to navigate. I have used process monitor to check it seems that chrome somehow used up 100% of my RAM. I know Chrome is RAM-consuming but this has to be bug right? I do have the habit of opening a lot of tabs in the same time but in the past it has never caused any problems.

steps I have taken:

updated my chrome to the latest version

restart my laptop

here is the log, not sure how to read it.

```
ate/Time:        2023-03-21 06:56:16.924 +0800
End time:         2023-03-21 06:56:32.319 +0800
OS Version:       macOS 13.2.1 (Build 22D68)
Architecture:     arm64e
Report Version:   40
Incident Identifier: B201EDCD-2B50-48C6-A5F9-48A51C86D545

Data Source:      Stackshots
Shared Cache:     835716AE-B363-3187-B065-CF94139BFC85 slid base address 0x1990ac000, slide 0x190ac000 (System Primary)
Shared Cache:     4CA2B729-8206-3C63-BADD-FAA0225AB773 slid base address 0x7ff81397c000, slide 0x1397c000 (Rosetta)
Shared Cache:     39FA3391-5698-38D6-B978-613210280134 slid base address 0x1eccf8000, slide 0x6ccf8000 (DriverKit)

Command:          Google Chrome
Path:             /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
Identifier:       com.google.Chrome
Version:          111.0.5563.64 (5563.64)
Team ID:          EQHXZ8M8AV
Is First Party:   No
Architecture:     arm64
Parent:           launchd [1]
PID:              3413
Time Since Fork:  20s

Event:            hang
Duration:         15.39s
Duration Sampled: 7.60s (process was unresponsive for 8 seconds before sampling)
Steps:            76 (100ms sampling interval)

Hardware model:   MacBookPro18,2
Active cpus:      10
HW page size:     16384
VM page size:     16384

Time Since Boot:  28121s
Time Awake Since Boot: 1954s
Time Since Wake:  1934s

Fan speed:        0 rpm
Total CPU Time:   11.818s (30.3G cycles, 109.1G instructions, 0.28c/i)
Advisory levels:  Battery -> 2, User -> 2, ThermalPressure -> 0, Combined -> 2
Free disk space:  334.98 GB/926.35 GB, low space threshold 3072 MB
Vnodes Available: 82.72% (217688/263168, 134893 allocated)

Preferred User Language: en-CN, zh-Hans-CN
Country Code:     CN
Keyboards:        Canadian - CSA, ABC
OS Cryptex File Extents: 2340

--------------------------------------------------
Timeline format: stacks are sorted chronologically
Use -i and -heavy to re-report with count sorting
--------------------------------------------------


Heaviest stack for the main thread of the target process:
  76  start + 2544 (dyld + 24144) [0x19914fe50]
  76  main + 196 (Google Chrome + 6500) [0x104de9964]
  76  ChromeMain + 312 (Google Chrome Framework + 19668) [0x11a738cd4]
  76  ChromeMain + 27050364 (Google Chrome Framework + 27069720) [0x11c104d18]
  76  ChromeMain + 27051572 (Google Chrome Framework + 27070928) [0x11c1051d0]
  76  ChromeMain + 27054856 (Google Chrome Framework + 27074212) [0x11c105ea4]
  76  ChromeMain + 35766808 (Google Chrome Framework + 35786164) [0x11c954db4]
  76  ChromeMain + 35768752 (Google Chrome Framework + 35788108) [0x11c95554c]
  76  ChromeMain + 35769156 (Google Chrome Framework + 35788512) [0x11c9556e0]
  76  ChromeMain + 13068380 (Google Chrome Framework + 13087736) [0x11b3af3f8]
  76  ChromeMain + 13070752 (Google Chrome Framework + 13090108) [0x11b3afd3c]
  76  ChromeMain + 30608012 (Google Chrome Framework + 30627368) [0x11c469628]
  76  ChromeMain + 38686576 (Google Chrome Framework + 38705932) [0x11cc1db0c]
  76  -[NSApplication run] + 464 (AppKit + 183820) [0x19c7d0e0c]
  76  ChromeMain + 44488492 (Google Chrome Framework + 44507848) [0x11d1a62c8]
  76  ChromeMain + 1161176 (Google Chrome Framework + 1180532) [0x11a854374]
  76  ChromeMain + 83542632 (Google Chrome Framework + 83561988) [0x11f6e4e04]
  76  -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 728 (AppKit + 231900) [0x19c7dc9dc]
  76  _DPSNextEvent + 632 (AppKit + 235596) [0x19c7dd84c]
```